# How come the CASE statement says "unexpected when after case"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to run the following code in a stored procedure:

```
CASE
    WHEN recordNotes=null AND sortNumber=null
        THEN INSERT INTO tempRecordHolder (union_ID,union_Name) VALUES (recordID, recordName);
    ELSE SET @blank="null";
END CASE;
```

"recordNotes", "sortNumber", "recordID", and "recordName" are variables passed into the stored procedure. My goal is to have it run that INSERT statement into my tempRecordHolder table that I make at the start of the function. But for some reason, it says "Unexpected WHEN after CASE." Any ideas? Thank You.

Full Code, please ignore the comments and commented out code. It is all stuff that is being worked on. The CASE is at line 34-41:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`apf15102`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_cu_LookUpTbls`(
    IN tbl_Name varchar(50),
    recordID int,
    recordName varChar(500),
    # REMEMBER THERE IS A DATE BETWEEN THESE TWO FIELDS IN THE TABLE STRUCTURES
    recordNotes longtext,
    sortNumber int,
    recordAlreadyExists bit
)
BEGIN

    #-------------------------------#
    # Begin preliminary table setup #
    #-------------------------------#

    # Begin by dropping my temp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempRecordHolder;

    # set my session variable equal to my passed in table name
    SET @tblName = tbl_Name;

    # create a session variable string that is the create table for the table that was passed in
    SET @tbl_Create_Command = concat("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempRecordHolder LIKE " , @tblName);

    # prepare the statement making it one string that can be executed then execute it
    prepare stmtCreate FROM @tbl_Create_Command;
    execute stmtCreate;

    #-----------------------------#
    # End preliminary table setup #
    #-----------------------------#


    # This code right here gives a "Syntax Error: Unexpected WHEN (when)" if it is un-commented
    /*
    CASE
        WHEN recordNotes IS NULL AND sortNumber IS NULL
            THEN INSERT INTO tempRecordHolder (union_ID,union_Name) VALUES (recordID, recordName);
        ELSE SET @blank="null";
    END CASE;
    */

    IF recordAlreadyExists = FALSE 
        THEN
            #-----------------------------------------------------------------#
            # Begin procedure for if the record DOES NOT exist in our records #
            #-----------------------------------------------------------------#
            IF sortNumber IS NULL
                THEN
                    INSERT INTO tempRecordHolder VALUES (recordID, recordName, curdate(), recordNotes);
            END IF;
            IF sortNumber IS NOT NUll
                THEN
                    INSERT INTO tempRecordHolder VALUES (recordID, recordName, curdate(), recordNotes, sortNumber);
            END IF;
            #---------------------------------------------------------------#
            # End procedure for if the record DOES NOT exist in our records #
            #---------------------------------------------------------------#
        ELSE  
            #-------------------------------------------------------------#
            # Begin procedure for if the record DOES exist in our records #
            #-------------------------------------------------------------#
            IF recordAlreadyExists = TRUE 
                THEN
                    SET @elsevar = null;
            END IF;
            #-----------------------------------------------------------#
            # END procedure for if the record DOES exist in our records #
            #-----------------------------------------------------------#
    END IF;
    /*
    #-----------------------------#
    # Begin data processing setup #
    #-----------------------------#

    # Declare all the necessary variables for making a cursor
    DECLARE finished BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE colNameForInsert varChar(50);
    DECLARE columnName CURSOR FOR
        (
            SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
            FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
            WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='tempRecordHolder';
        );
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = TRUE;

    #---------------------------#
    # END data processing setup #
    #---------------------------#

    #--------------------------------#
    # Begin main loop and processing #
    #--------------------------------#

    OPEN columnName;
    manFunc: loop

        # check to see if we are done before running the rest of the loop
        IF finished = TRUE THEN
            LEAVE mainFunc;
        END IF;
        FETCH columnName INTO colNameForInsert;

        IF 

    END LOOP mainFunc;
    CLOSE columnName;

    #------------------------------#
    # END main loop and processing #
    #------------------------------#

    */

END
```

Comment: I was trying to use a CASE statement, is not that right? http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php#MIF

Comment: @AndréFecteau . . . You should show more of the code before this.  You should also note that `= null` is simply incorrect.  Because of this, I suspect that all your code is likely to be poorly written.

Comment: to close CASE you must use END. Equality check with NULL must do with IS NULL and not =

Comment: @GordonLinoff as I said in another comment. Just because I used =null doesn't mean the rest of my code is poorly written. I come from a C++/Java background and have self-taught the SQL I know. I made a simple mistake moving between languages.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the entirety of the code is shown in the post now.

Answer (score 2):

A `case` expression returns a value. You can't use it to insert values into a table. I think you need [`IF/ELSE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).

```
IF recordNotes is null AND sortNumber is null
THEN INSERT INTO tempRecordHolder (union_ID,union_Name) VALUES (recordID, recordName);
ELSE SET @blank='null';
END IF;
```

Also comparison with `null` (=null or <> null) always returns unknown. Use `is null`.

Comment: Nope, you can use `case` in stored procedure for complex conditions. You can use inserts as well within a `case`. The `is null` is a good spot, also in this particular case `if` can be used in place of ¬case`, however the answer fails to explain why the code on the question produces the error message provided.

Comment: @Shadow My original plan was to use IF/ELSE but I figured I was going to try and use a CASE statement to make it cleaner but it seems that the CASE statement won't work from the other comments above.

Comment: @AndréFecteau nope, those comments are not correct. I also agree with Gordon's comment: you need to copy the statements before the `case` as well to understand what may have gone wrong. You can use `case` to execute an insert and `case` is terminated by `end case` and not just by `end`.

Comment: @Shadow yeah I know the end case is right If I try to just do "end" it gives an error saying it's missing case. I disagree with Gordon, just because I used =null doesn't mean my code is poorly written. I come from a C++ / Java background and have taught myself all the SQL that I know. I made a simple mistake moving between languages, it doesn't mean my code is poorly written.

Comment: And therefore you may have committed other mistakes in your code that would explain the error message you received. Your code in the question should not produce the syntax error you described.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if the error message comes from MySQL at all. phpmyadmin does some pre-parsing of queries, is not it possible that the error was raised by the gui you are using and not by MySQL?

Comment: @Shadow I am using MySQL Workbench and not using PHPMyAdmin. (Windows Server running IIS and MySQL Server installed.)

Comment: @shadow here is the rest of the code: pastebin.com/iSiRsWk1 There are a lot of comments and commented out code that I am currently working on. You are looking for line 34-41

Comment: I cannot access pastebin from where I'm now.

Comment: @Shadow see the OP, the code is too long for a comment. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you use the `delimiter` statement before the create procedure and after the final `end`?

Comment: @Shadow yeah, when MySQL workbench applies a Stored Procedure to the server, it does the delimiter statement for me.

Comment: Well, the error message does not come from MySQL, I cannot find any error message that would read `syntax error: unexpected <keyword>`. MySQL's syntax error has a different message. Nothing may be wrong with your syntax. I would try to execute the above code using MySQL's command line client.